# Android studio sdk not being downloaded

Tags: android, sdk

Hello i have downloaded android studio recently and got a little problem .
After following the intallation it appeared that i don't have an sdk

I opened sdk manager and it says

**The Android SDK location cannot be in the filesystem root**

I clicked edit and chose a location to download sdk but it says

> Nothing to do! Android SDK is up to date. SDK emulator directory is
> missing**

And whenever I try to create a project it says

> SDK Problem.Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted.

Can you please tell me why am I getting this ?
And how can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use hostname:8080 as your proxy settings

Answer (score 0):

That day I tried an uninstall reinstall of three versions of Android Studio; After trying to restart, delete the obtained SDK folder; But the Android SDK page is always grayed out. Finally, the download of SDK is completed normally after changing the VPN agent and detecting that the [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) can be accessed and the software is opened again.
[image]